# assign section to variable

Tags: php, laravel, sections

I have a section:

```
@section('info') 
code 
@endsection
```

I want to assign the section to a variable `$output`. Is this possible? For example `echo $output` would echo the output from the section. I know I can use `@yield('info')` but I can't use `@yield` in if statements etc.

Comment: Why you can't use ```@yield``` in an ```@if statement```?

Comment: maybe I can, but I got the error  `I get the error The "yield" expression can only be used inside a function.` on the line: `if(strpos(@yield('info'), $closed_text) !== false){`